# Why milk is not vegan?

Tags: diet, vegetarian, milk

I asked the same question to many persons but none of them gave me a satistfied answer.

**If you want to say milk contains BACTERIA thats why its not vegan then every thing in the world would not be a vegan**

I want a pure technical reason why is it so??

Comment: There is a nutrition stack exchange. In this one, we answer questions that relate to exercise. But for the record; vegans don't eat products that come from animals. Milk typically comes from cows or goats. There are other types like coconut milk and almond milk which are, of course, accepted by vegans.

Answer (score 3):

> An animal product is any material derived from the body of an animal. Examples are fat, flesh, blood, milk, eggs, and lesser known products, such as isinglass and rennet.

So milk is clearly an animal product.

> Veganism is both the practice of abstaining from the use of animal products, particularly in diet, and an associated philosophy that rejects the commodity status of animals.[9] A follower of veganism is known as a vegan.

Hence vegans do not drink milk.

Source: wikipedia

Comment: so would i change defination of vegan which is in my mind..

Comment: Yes, what is your current definition of veganism in your mind?

Comment: Actually according to me vegan is something like vegeterian in which there is no kind of 'animal' killing involved for food desire

Comment: @ShubhamNigam Just call yourself a vegetarian.  Being a vegan has a lot more to do with philosophy than food choice.

Comment: Yes that would be one type of vegetarianism and not veganism according to official definitions.